# WebView Control Metro Style App

Tags: webview, microsoft-metro

How to send parameters with URL in source properties of webview control in metro style app.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

You just add them to the URL.

```
 source="http://myurl/?param1=hello&param2=world"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or can also inject a javascript file to communicate with the webpage:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///js/script.js");
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
string text = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file); //reading content as string
var script = "(function(){" + text + "})()";
```